# How to get date with next format?

Tags: node.js

I am using node.js and want to get date with format :

```
Sun July 16th
```

From

var myDate = new Date();

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myDate = new Date();
var formatted = moment(myDate).format('ddd MMMM Mo');
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 2):

You can use momentJs library for it. Check this out: https://momentjs.com/docs/